# C9: there is a (Psych::SyntaxError). the rails server doesn't work

Tags: ruby, c9.io

> ```
> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285:
> ```
>
> warning: circular argument reference - now
>       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context
>   at line 7 column 24 (Psych::SyntaxError)
>               from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in`
>   parse_stream'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:325:in
>   `parse'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:252:in`load'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:60:in
>   `parse'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in`
>   block in raw_configuration'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:56:in
>   `raw_configuration'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:64:in`
>   global_configuration'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in
>   `configuration'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in`
>   each'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in
>   `load'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro.rb:23:in`
>   load'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/figaro-1.0.0/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in
>   `block in <class:Railtie>'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`
>   execute_hook'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in
>   `block in run_load_hooks'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`
>   each'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in
>   `run_load_hooks'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:123:in`
>   initialize'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in
>   `new'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:171:in`
>   instance'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:90:in
>   `inherited'
>               from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/config/application.rb:10:in`
>   '
>               from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/config/application.rb:9:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in`
>   require'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in
>   `block in server'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in`
>   tap'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in
>   `server'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in`
>   run_command!'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>               from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/rails:9:in`require'
>               from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/rails:9:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   load'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `call'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`
>   call'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in
>   `run'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in`
>   '
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in
>   `load'
>               from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`
>   '
>               from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/spring:13:in `require'
>               from /home/ubuntu/workspace/simplecodecasts_saas/bin/spring:13:in`'
>               from bin/rails:3:in `load'
>               from bin/rails:3:in`'

this is my application.yml:

> ```
> # Add configuration values here, as shown below.
> #
> # pusher_app_id: "2954"
> # pusher_key: "..........."
> # pusher_secret: "..........."
> ```
>
> stripe_api_key: ".............."
>   stripe_publishable_key: ".........."
>       #  production:
>     stripe_api_key: ".............."
>    stripe_publishable_key: "......"

the dots were for security reasons. sorry. but stuff is there

Comment: this error happens when there's a syntax error in YAML. can you show your config/application.yml?

Comment: This is my config/application.yml:

Comment: what command are you running which shows this error? did you try to prepend `bundle exec`?

Comment: Yes i used bundle exec rails s -p $PORT -b $IP in cloud 9 and thats the error that showed up

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?  I'm getting a similar error "at line 30 column 28" when none of my YAML files are 30 lines long